# check if a object exists within a set() python

Tags: python, set

I have a problem with python when I do this:

```
# initialise vistited set
visited = set()
# Add Node to visited set
self.visited.add(Node(2, 1)) 
# set a current node 
currentNode = Node(2, 1)
# Check if the currentNode is in visited
if currentNode in self.visited:
    print("Node is in visited")
```

Now this above does not work, I don't know why its not checking if an object Node is in a set?

The Node definition:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Any help or tips will be appreciated!

Comment: There's an inconsistency between `visited` and `self.visited` - is this code in a class or not?

Comment: Yes its within a class

Comment: Then shouldn't it be `self.visited = set()` ?

Comment: Along with the inconsistency mentioned above, you need to decide what equality means among nodes. Are two different objects with the same x and y equal or distinct? If you want them to be considered the same by the set, you need to define `__eq()__` and `__hash()__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
self.visited.add(Node(2, 1))
```

Creates a new `Node()` object and adds it to visited.

This line:

```
currentNode = Node(2, 1)
```

Creates a new `Node` object and assigns it to `currentNode`. Although `currentNode` and the most recently added element of `self.visited` are identicial objects (assuming they are constructed deterministically from the parameters of the constructor), they are not *the same object*.

So, the node `currentNode` points at is not `in self.visited`.

Compare:

```
# initialise vistited set
visited = set()
# set a current node 
currentNode = Node(2, 1)
# Add Node to visited set
visited.add(currentNode) 
# Check if the currentNode is in visited
if currentNode in visited:
    print("Node is in visited")
```

Here only one `Node` object is created, which is added to the set.

(`self` was left off, since the example doesn't actually sit inside a method, but it would be the same if it did - although your code seems to be missing `self.` on the first reference to `visited`)

This may be confusing if you compare it to this:

```
x = 1
y = 1
numbers = {y}

if x in numbers:
    print('yes')
```

However, the reason this prints `yes` is that numbers aren't separate objects. There's only one `1`, one `2`, etc. in Python and similarly, two string variables that both have the value `'test'` effectively refer to 'the same string'.

This works because you can't modify part of a string or an integer. But with other (or at least mutable) object types, that's not true.

For example, for tuples (another immutable type):

```
x = (1,)
y = (1,)
tuples = {y}

if x in tuples:
    print('yes')
```

Again, this prints `yes`.

But for lists, a mutable type:

```
x = [1]
y = [1]
lists = {y}

if x in lists:
    print('yes')
```

This won't even run, because a `list` is not a hashable type.

Your `Node` is an example of a hashable, but mutable type. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html): "Objects which are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default. They all compare unequal (except with themselves), and their hash value is derived from their id()."

Note: people suggested in the comments that adding an equality method (i.e. `__eq__`) would help, but it won't unless you also add a `__hash__` function, as user @Mark also points out - not doing so makes the object no longer hashable and adding it to a set won't work.

So, this is an example of how you *can* make it work:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.x, self.y))


visited = set()
visited.add(Node(2, 1))

x = Node(2, 1)
if x in visited:
    print('it is in there')
```

Comment: It's also a good idea for `__eq__` to check that `other` is the same or compatible type as `self`. `other` might have attributes with the same names and values, but might not be a `Node`.

Comment: @sj95126 although that's certainly not bad advice to consider, there's no universal way to check that which always applies. Even something like `isinstance(other, self.__class__)` isn't always right - what if you want equality for other classes that also implement `.x` and `.y` attributes? What if you're comparing instances of two descendant classes? I decided to leave it out, since it's not relevant to the question and introduces other complexity.